# Binding a bool property to BackColor Property of a WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, binding

I have a `Form` in my `WinForm` application, that contains a `TextBox` and this `TextBox` bind to `FirstName` property of a `Person` Object.

```
public class Person
{
   string firstName;
   public string FirstName
   {
      get { return firstName; }
      set { 
           firstName = value; 
           this.isOdd = value.Length % 2;
          }
   }

   bool isOdd;  
   public bool IsOdd { get {return isOdd; } }
}
```

When My application runs, this `Form` shows and user could types his/her name to the TextBox, How can I bind `BackColor` property of the `Form` to the `IsOdd` Property of `Person` object(when `IsOdd` is `True` `BackColor` set to `Color.Green` and when it is `False` the `BackColor` set to `Color.Red`)?

Comment: Can you post some code of binding the name property to the textbox text?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Binding` in `winforms` also has something very similar to `wpf`. In `WPF` you have `Converter` and yes in `winforms` it's supported by an event called `Format`. You can try this code:

```
Binding bind = new Binding("BackColor", person, "IsOdd");
bind.Format += (s, e) => {
   e.Value = (bool)e.Value ? Color.Green : Color.Red;
};
control.DataBindings.Add(bind);
```

For the class `Person`, you have to modify it a little. In `winforms` there is a pattern to notify changes is by using the event with name `EventNameChanged` together with the raiser named `OnEventNameChanged`. You can find this pattern is implemented **mostly** in `winforms`. You can also use `INotifyPropertyChanged` which is more familiar in `WPF`. Here is the modified class:

```
public class Person {
  string firstName;
  public string FirstName {
     get { return firstName; }
     set {
           firstName = value;
           IsOdd = value.Length % 2 != 0;//Note use IsOdd not isOdd
         }
  }
  bool isOdd;
  public bool IsOdd {
    get { return isOdd; }
    private set { 
         if(isOdd != value){
           isOdd = value;
           OnIsOddChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
         }
    }
    public event EventHandler IsOddChanged;
    protected virtual void OnIsOddChanged(EventArgs e) {
      var handler = IsOddChanged;
      if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
    }        
}
```

**NOTE** You can use `private set` to allow all private code to change the property `IsOdd` via the setter and notify the changes correctly, using the private variable `isOdd` won't notify changes unless you have to append some notifying code after that. This code is also **Tested!**.

Answer (score 1):

You can't exactly bind a `Color` property to `bool` you'll have to do something like this.
Add a readonly property of type `Color` depends on your boolean and bind it.

```
internal class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isOdd;
    public bool IsOdd 
    {
        get
        {
            return _isOdd;
        }
        set
        {
            _isOdd = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsOdd"));
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Color"));
            }
        }
    }

    public Color Color
    {
        get
        {
            return (IsOdd) ? Color.Green : Color.Red;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Then just bind this class instance to the `BackColor` property of any control.

```
control.DataBindings.Add("BackColor", myclass, "Color");
```

Note: `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface implementation is must, only then when there is a change in your property that will reflect in bindings immediately.

Comment: Are you sure this is System.Windows.Forms? Because it looks just like WPF.

Comment: @nvoigt What makes you think this is WPF? this is absolutely "Winforms" lives in `System.Windows.Forms.dll`. btw am not familiar with WPF :) I just tested it with `Form` before posting, it works.

Comment: You are right, it seems WinForms databinding works a lot more like WPF than I thought. Never knew I know WinForms Binding :)